# equal sizing of column height bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have created a React Social Card component using Bootstrap. I want all the cards to be the same size. However, the first card is rendering much larger than the other two. I have tried unsuccessfully to manipulate the CSS to fix this problem but unfortunately, I am a novice with Bootstrap. I have also tried exporting this project into Codesandbox from the Github repository I have it stored in to make it easier to help me find the solution. I am getting this error there: Error importing GitHub repository: Could not find package.json.

Anyway, does anyone know the solution to this problem? Below, I will share a screenshot to illustrate the problem as well as the code for the relevant components and CSS file. Here is the link to the Github repository: https://github.com/jevoncochran/React-Social-Card

Here is the Cards component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "./CardUI";

import img1 from "../assets/me-telice-pelo.jpg";
import img2 from "../assets/me-pernambues.jpg";
import img3 from "../assets/me-lucas-walking-pernambues.jpg";

class Cards extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img1} title="Convergeance" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="Continuation" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img3} title="Conspiracy" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cards;
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
body {
    background: radial-gradient(#e5e5e5, #ffff, #e5e5e5);
}

.card {
    width: 20rem;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.253) !important;
}

.card-body {
    padding: 3rem 0 !important;
}

.card-text {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 0.4rem 1.9rem;
}

.container-fluid .row {
    padding: 6rem;
}

.overflow { 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-img-top {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
    transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out a solution. I'm not sure it's the best solution out there. But I determined that the problem was that the first image is bigger than the other two images. In my CSS, I just set the maximum height of the all images to the height of the last two (211.938px).